# Can't change my mongodb collection streams dynamically in flask

Tags: javascript, mongodb, flask

The first html code is my front-end and I would like to make the added small DIV's clickable and when are clicked the stream of the data should be disconnected so it can be connected to the new stream, each of the small DIV's values are basically the collection names of a mongodb database. I have tried all different changes but I can't figure-out,can someone help me make the correct changes.  Also I'm including the flask back-end code.

Front-end code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Flask.SSE Geolocation Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden; /* Hide scroll bars */
    }

    #top-bar {
      background-color: #333;
      color: white;
      padding: 25px; /* Adjust the top bar height */
      text-align: center;
      z-index: 2; /* Ensure the top bar is above other elements */
    }

    #map-container {
      position: relative;
    }

    #map {
      width: 100vw;
      height: calc(100vh - 15px); /* Adjust the top bar height */
    }

    #data {
      position: fixed;
      top: 10px;
      right: 10px;
      color: white;
      font-size: 14px;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
      padding: 10px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      z-index: 1; /* Ensure the data element is above the map */
    }

    #floating-box {
      position: absolute;
      left: 10px;
      top: 10px;
      width: 150px;
      height: 300px;
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      padding: 10px;
      overflow-y: auto; 
      z-index: 1000;
    }

    #top-container {
      position: sticky; /* Change to sticky */
      top: 0;
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
      display: flex;
      justify-content: flex-end;
      z-index: 1; /* Ensure it stays above the scrollable content */
  }

    #description {
      margin-right: 5px;
    }

    #add-button {
      margin-left: 5px;
    }

  

  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="top-bar">
    
  </div>

  <div id="map-container">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="data">Waiting for data...</div>
    <div id="floating-box">
      
        <div id="top-container">
          <span id="description">Add Device:</span>
          <button id="add-button" onclick="addButtonClick()">Add</button>
          
        </div>

      
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      //const map = L.map('map').setView([45.825866, 16.043631], 13);  // Set initial coordinates to Zagreb
      const map = L.map('map', { zoomControl: false // Disable the default zoom control
    }).setView([45.825866, 16.043631], 13);  // Set initial coordinates to Zagreb

      


      L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      }).addTo(map);

      L.control.zoom({ position: 'topright' }).addTo(map);

      const marker = L.marker([45.825866, 16.043631]).addTo(map);    // Set initial marker position to Zagreb

      const receivedCoordinates = [];
      const trace = L.polyline([], {color: 'red'}).addTo(map);

      const source = new EventSource("/stream");
      source.onmessage = async function(event) {
        try {
          const data = JSON.parse(event.data);

          document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = 'Lat: ' + data.Lat.toFixed(4) + ', Lng: ' + data.Lng.toFixed(4);
          marker.setLatLng([data.Lat, data.Lng]);
          map.setView([data.Lat, data.Lng], map.getZoom());

          receivedCoordinates.push(L.latLng(data.Lat, data.Lng));
          trace.setLatLngs(receivedCoordinates);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error parsing server-sent data:', error);
        }
      };
    });
  </script>

<script>
  function addButtonClick() {
      const id = prompt("Enter ID:");
      const description = prompt("Enter Description:");

      fetch('/add_item', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({id, description})
      })
      .then(response=> response.json())
      .then(data => {
          if (data.status === "success") {
              const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
              newDiv.textContent = description;

              // Add a remove button to each div
              const removeButton = document.createElement("button");
              removeButton.textContent = "Remove";
              removeButton.onclick = function() {
                  removeItem(id, newDiv);
              };
              newDiv.appendChild(removeButton);

              newDiv.style.border = "1px solid black";
              newDiv.style.padding = "5px";
              newDiv.style.marginTop = "5px";
              newDiv.classList.add("added-container"); // Add a class to the new div
              document.getElementById("floating-box").appendChild(newDiv);
          } else {
              alert("Error adding item");
          }
      });
  }

  function removeItem(id, div) {
      fetch('/remove_item', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({id})
      })
      .then(response=> response.json())
      .then(data => {
          if (data.status === "success") {
              div.remove(); // Remove the corresponding div from the UI
          } else {
              alert("Error removing item");
          }
      });
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Back-end code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response, stream_with_context, jsonify, request
from pymongo import MongoClient
import json
import threading
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

# Replace the following line with your MongoDB Atlas connection string
client = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://test[enter image description here][1]:XfZOOYjLLN8c4hs2@cluster0.jlosawe.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority")

# Access the 'test' database using dictionary-style notation
db = client['test']

collection = db.coordinates

items=[]

def event_stream():
    with collection.watch() as stream:
        while stream.alive:
            change = stream.try_next()
            if change is not None and 'fullDocument' in change:
                new_data = change['fullDocument']
                new_data['_id'] = str(new_data['_id'])
                yield f"data: {json.dumps(new_data)}\n\n"
            else:
                time.sleep(1)

@app.route('/stream')
def stream():
    return Response(event_stream(), content_type='text/event-stream')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/add_item', methods=['POST'])
def add_item():
    data = request.get_json()
    id = data.get('id')
    description = data.get('description')

    if id and description:
        items.append({'id': id, 'description': description})
        print("ITEMS: ",items)
        return jsonify({'status': 'success'})
    else:
        return jsonify({'status': 'error'})
    
@app.route('/remove_item', methods=['POST'])
def remove_item():
    data = request.get_json()
    id = data.get('id')

    if id:
        # Remove the item from the backend
        for item in items:
            if item['id'] == id:
                items.remove(item)
                print("ITEMS: ", items)
                return jsonify({'status': 'success'})
        return jsonify({'status': 'error', 'message': 'Item not found'})
    else:
        return jsonify({'status': 'error', 'message': 'Invalid request'})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```